# How to apply jqueryUI method on dynamically generated content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamically-generated

Does anyone can help me with applying jqueryUI method to dynamically generated content in my webapp.
This content here is generated dynamically through an ajax call-:

```
<div class="streamOptionsContainer">
<button id="delete_post" title="Delete Post"></button>
</div>
```

problem is that when I use jqueryUI method:-

```
$("button[id=delete_post]").button();
```

on the dynamically generated button it doesn't work, while the above mentioned jqueryUI method is working for all static content.

Comment: Yes you can use jquery function in success mehtod of $.ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.on()` method.

```
$("button[id=delete_post]").on("load", function(){
    $(this).button();
});
```

Since you are using an ID, you can do this way:

```
$("#delete_post").on("load", function(){
    $(this).button();
});
```

Also, if you are loading it after an ajax call, you can use the `success:` function in it.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(){
        $("#delete_post").button();
    }
});
```

Correct my syntax if wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be caused by bootstrap (if you use it). Bootstrap rewrites `$.fn.button` with its own method. But this is fixed. Please look at the code from bootstrap.js

```
var old = $.fn.button

$.fn.button = function (option) {
 return this.each(function () {
   var $this = $(this)
     , data = $this.data('button')
     , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
   if (!data) $this.data('button', (data = new Button(this, options)))
   if (option == 'toggle') data.toggle()
   else if (option) data.setState(option)
 })
}

...

$.fn.button.noConflict = function () {
  $.fn.button = old
  return this
}
```

So we need to write `$.fn.button.noConflict();` to make jQuery Ui Button available via calling `.button()` on element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$('#delete_post').button();
```